# I have an 2000 buick lesabre and it’s shooting out and leaking water from the side of the engine every time I drive it

Tags: buick, lesabre

[image] [image]

I have an 2000 buick lesabre and it’s shooting out and leaking water from the side of the engine every time I drive it it was trying to over heat because of a hole in the transmission line to the radiator the hose has been replaced and now the before expressed problem is present

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is that where the leak is from? That is the front of the engine if the pulley below is the crank pulley.

Comment: Yes the spot circled is where the water is leaking from

Comment: All the coolant leaks out of that connection causing the radiator to be empty and the car to run hot

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Those coolant elbows are made from plastic, they soften and break over time. IIRC Dorman makes a replacement part that's plastic. Sometimes you can find them made from metal, I believe it's Dorman as well.

The alternator bracket needs to be removed to do the job. Obviously the coolant needs to be drained. Make sure you replace both elbows, the other can't be seen in the pictures.